Why were the broken Luchos not in the Aron that was in the Kodesh Hakodoshim
in Bamidbar 10:33 the Pasuk says:

וַיִּסְעוּ֙ מֵהַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֔ה דֶּ֖רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֑ים וַאֲר֨וֹן בְּרִית־יְהֹוָ֜ה נֹסֵ֣עַ לִפְנֵיהֶ֗ם דֶּ֚רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֔ים לָת֥וּר לָהֶ֖ם מְנוּחָֽה׃
They marched from the mountain of יהוה a distance of three days. The Ark of the Covenant of יהוה traveled in front of them on that three days’ journey to seek out a resting place for them;

Rashi on this Pasukexplains that it is referring to the Aron that went along when war was waged and in which the broken Luchos were placed

וארון ברית ה' נסע לפניהם דרך שלשת ימים. זֶה הָאָרוֹן הַיּוֹצֵא עִמָּהֶם לַמִּלְחָמָה וּבוֹ שִׁבְרֵי לוּחוֹת מוּנָחִים, וּמַקְדִּים לִפְנֵיהֶם דֶּרֶךְ שְׁלֹשֶׁת יָמִים, לְתַקֵּן לָהֶם מְקוֹם חֲנִיָּה (שם; תלמוד ירושלמי שקלים ו'):
וארון ברית ה' נסע לפניהם דרך שלשת ימים
AND THE ARK OF THE COVENANT OF THE LORD WENT BEFORE THEM IN THE THREE DAYS' JOURNEY — This was the Ark that went with them whenever they waged war and in which the broken Tablets were placed. It traveled in front of them a distance of three days’ journey to prepare for them a proper place for encampment (Sifrei Bamidbar 82; Talmud Yerushalmi Shekalim 6:1).

This was a different Aron than the one placed in the Kodesh Kodoshim (see Sifsei Chahomim on this Pasuk- Thanks @shumel for providing this source)
How can we reconcile this with the Gemara in Bava Batra 14b, that writes the the broken Luchos were placed alongside the second Luchos in the Aron that was put in the Kodesh Kodoshim?
Especially acording to Rav Yosef who leans this halacha from the Torah, Devarim 10:2 (proving that already Moshe had the commandment to place the Luchos in the Aron with the second Luchos)

דְּתָנֵי רַב יוֹסֵף: ״אֲשֶׁר שִׁבַּרְתָּ וְשַׂמְתָּם״ – מְלַמֵּד שֶׁהַלּוּחוֹת וְשִׁבְרֵי לוּחוֹת מוּנָּחִין בָּאָרוֹן


"It seems like this was a different Aron than the one placed in the Kodesh Kodoshim." - why?

@Shmuel rashi makes a point of saying that "this was the aron that went to war" if there was only one aron, then that sentence is unnecessary

You are right. I just saw this Siftei Chachamim.

@Shmuel thanks, i will use it and update my question.

they used a different aron for war. the one time they took the aron hakodesh it was taken by the plishtim. Going from memory, There is a tosafos on the sugya that asks about seeming contradictions regarding the broken luchot and the aron, and answers that it was shlomo hamelech who put them in the same aron, before that they were separate.

see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9596/was-there-space-in-the-aron-for-two-sets-of-luchot

If I am not mistaken, the sifsi chachomim is working with one of the opinions there in shekalim that says there were 2 arons, however that is an argument there, as another opinion says there was only one. I believe the gemara in baba basra is going according to that opinion.

Can we say that really the Luchot were in Kodosh Hakodashim but whenever they went to war they transported it to the other Aron? - no source or logic as to why they would do this (and how because you can’t just go into the Kodosh Hakodashim) but just a thought
